# How to see the installed programs in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have ubuntu and I have installed some programs through commands. Which commands do I use to see if these programs have been installed? (not ALL the packages, just programs).

Comment: define program. Do you mean commands? Applications? Scripts?

Comment: By program I mean, for example, openssh, webmin, all installed by commands like sudo apt-get or wget. I only installed 3 or 4 programs, but i need to see if they are installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21057/203214)

> There is generally no way of listing manually installed programs and their components. This is not recorded anywhere if you didn't use a package manager. All you can do is find the binaries in standard locations (like Chris suggested) and in a similar way, guess where some libraries or some manual pages etc. came from. That is why, whenever possible, you should always install programs using your package manager.